# Matlab: Get elements of Cell Array from Indices

Tags: arrays, matlab, validation, cell, indices

I have a 1x84 cell array that I get the indices for cross validation:

```
indices = crossvalind('Kfold',length(filenames),k_fold);
for i = 1:k_fold
    test = (indices == i);
    train = ~test;
```

Given test and train (84x1 logical arrays of 1 or 0) how do I get all filenames that are indexed by test/train?

Comment: `filenames(test)` and `filenames(train)`?

Comment: If you have cell array than filenames{test} / filenames{train} (with curly brackets)

Answer (score 0):

You could apply logical indexing on the cell array to slice it. Here is simplified example:

```
%# create a cell array of string
C = cellstr(num2str((1:5)', 'file %d'));

%# random split
trainIdx = rand(size(C)) > 0.5;
testIdx = ~trainIdx;

%# slice cell array
tr = C(trainIdx)
ts = C(testIdx)
```

Note that both `tr` and `ts` are cell arrays of string themselves. So to access the first string in `tr`, you do:

```
>> tr{1}
```